# Is there an expression for ‘bad news’ when meant literally for negative news we get from the media?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

> We are checking bad news every day. Should we constantly be informed
> about all that _______ ?

I need an idiom or expression for a context like the above.

Comment: One idiom for constantly negative news is 'doom and gloom'.

Comment: A recent widely-used phrase for any news that one doesn't like is _fake news._

Comment: @KateBunting This is very relative and can be offered in an answer. Although Merriam Webster says ‘gloom and doom’.

Comment: @JohnLawler aren't "fake news" and "bad news" different? "Covid cured!" is fake news but not "doom and gloom".

Comment: It depends on who you ask.

Comment: If you're talking about online news sources, the latest idiom is [doomscrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomscrolling)

Comment: @LaconicDroid This is interesting. Would it be like ‘doom scrolling news’? This can be developed into an answer.

Comment: @Sasan - thanks. I expanded on doomscrolling as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the term ***negativity***:

> an attitude that is not hopeful or enthusiastic
> *There's too much negativity in the world today.*
>
> (From the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/negativity))

> *He was taken aback by the negativity of the press.*
>
> *The blanket of media negativity, he says, still raises the hackles.*
>
> (Examples from [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/negativity))

If you're looking for a phrase, then, as [suggested](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/589604/is-there-an-idiom-for-bad-news-when-meant-literally-for-negative-news-we-get-f#comment1479400_589604) by Kate Bunting, there's ***gloom and doom***:

> **gloom and doom**
> <sub>noun</sub>
>
> : sad and tragic events : a feeling or attitude that things are only
> getting worse
> *The papers are filled with stories of gloom and doom.*
> *She was full of gloom and doom.*
>
> (From [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gloom%20and%20doom))

It can also be written as [***doom and gloom***](https://www.lexico.com/definition/doom_and_gloom).

---

> We are checking bad news every day. Should we constantly be informed about all that *negativity*?

> We are checking bad news every day. Should we constantly be informed about all that *gloom and doom*?

> We are checking bad news every day. Should we constantly be informed about all that *doom and gloom*?

Comment: As a Brit, ***gloom and doom*** stood out to me as being somewhat on a par with ***horses and coach***. But checking NGrams, I see that was in fact the most common sequence [for American publications](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gloom+and+doom%2Cdoom+and+gloom&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3) until a couple of decades ago (the collocation barely existed before WW2 anyway). But [we Brits seem to have promoted our usage well.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gloom+and+doom%2Cdoom+and+gloom&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3)

Comment: +1 for doom and gloom -- it fits very well in the sample sentence.

Answer (score 5):

### "Bleeds"

This is specific to your example, and will not generalize. There, however, it is the exact match. It references an idiom describing (many) current news sources:

"If it bleeds, it leads."[*]

Essentially, this references an opinion that many media sources are selling fear. They are creating uncertainty and dread, and that uncertainty drives you back to that source for reassurance. This is not a new or fringe opinion; indeed you can trivially find many explanations tracing it back to Hearst and the Spanish-American War, as well as attestations to the phrase's regular use in newsrooms from the 70's on.

See e.g. the explanation [here](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/two-takes-depression/201106/if-it-bleeds-it-leads-understanding-fear-based-media):

> The success of fear-based news relies on presenting dramatic anecdotes
> in place of scientific evidence, promoting isolated events as trends,
> depicting categories of people as dangerous and replacing optimism
> with fatalistic thinking.

So when you say, "We are checking bad news every day. Should we constantly be informed about all that *bleeds*?" you are deliberately referencing this view of the media. This appears to align well with the point you're trying to make, so you should use the reference.

---

[*] Or sometimes "ledes". The lede is the hook which makes you want to read the story.   Good practice puts it at the beginning, which gives us another idiom "burying the lede."

Answer (score 1):

In recent Covid-19 times, 2 new and related terms have been coined:

***Doomscrolling*** and ***Doomsurfing***

These are specific to online news where one might continue to surf the web or scroll through news sites on your phone.

[Mirriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/doomsurfing-doomscrolling-words-were-watching) has this to say on the terms

> ***Doomscrolling*** and ***doomsurfing*** are new terms referring to the tendency
> to continue to surf or scroll through bad news, even though that news
> is saddening, disheartening, or depressing. Many people are finding
> themselves reading continuously bad news about COVID-19 without the
> ability to stop or step back.

Doomscrolling seems to be used more often than doomsurfing, at least in the UK.

From an article in [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2020/oct/19/doomscrolling-social-media-apocalyptic-updates-cure):

> What I’ve been doing is called doomscrolling, a term that has caught
> on during this year’s pandemic. For those who still dwell mostly
> offline, doomscrolling (and, less commonly, doomsurfing) is “the
> tendency to continue to surf or scroll through bad news, even though
> that news is saddening, disheartening, or depressing”.
>
> There’s a compulsiveness to doomscrolling. We are looking for
> something, even though we are not sure exactly what it is
> (reassurance? Truth? Validation? Answers? A vaccine?). Some of us are,
> perhaps, in fight-or-flight mode, and the constant scrolling is a kind
> of hypervigilance.

Answer (score -1):

## Hate-mongering

Try the term my grandmother often used. It conveniently applies directly to *speech* and *writing*, which matches the *news* aspect of your Question.

**hate-mongering** ([Oxford Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/hate-mongering))

> The arousal of feelings of hatred using speech or writing

By relation, the *person* who does the *hate-mongering*...

**hatemonger** ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hatemonger))

> someone who tries to encourage people to hate other people or groups

It certainly stands to reason that you could view the news reporters in your example as *hatemongers*.

### Used in your example:

If you choose this word, I would tweak the wording of your example sentence from *about* to *by*. Both could work, but this flows better...

> We are checking bad news every day. Should we constantly be informed *by* all that ***hate-mongering***?

Comment: But bad news might be just sad or upsetting, without arousing hate toward anybody or anything.

Comment: @Sasan True. But, the person wanting to use this term might view the news by the effect it has.